# Can I assign a foreign key from two tables?

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-8, foreign-keys

I am creating a database which is similar to the following situation.

Table1:

CustomerType1 (Column: CustomerId,...)

Table2:

CustomerType2 (Column: CustomerId,...)

Table 3:

Orders (Columns: OrderId, CustomerId...)

Now, how can I relate the customerId of orders table to customerId column of CustomerType1 and CustomerType2 tables?

(I am working on a windows phone app, so if you can help me with the attributes used in creating a database similar to above situation than it would be helpful)

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

Your database should be composed of 4 tables:

```
 - Customer(CustomerId, common stuff to all customers)
 - CustomerType1(CustomerId, specific stuff to type 1 customers)
 - CustomerType2(CustomerId, specific stuff to type 2 customers)
 - Orders(OrderId, CustomerId, other order stuff)
```

The table columns `CustomerType1.CustomerId` and `CustomerType2.CustomerId` provide a reference to the Customer table by means of the `Customer.CustomerId` column. Also a reference to the Orders table and Customer table can be achieved by using the  `Orders.CustomerId` and `Customer.CustomerId` columns.

For clarity, the tables `CustomerType1`, `CustomerType2` and `Orders` would all have a Foreign key constraint as following:

```
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerId)
```

Comment: But again how will i reference the customerId of Customer table to customerId of both previous tables. Again the situation is similar.

Comment: No, what you do is you make CustomerType1.CustomerId reference Customer.CustomerId and CustomerType2.CustomerId reference Customer.CustomerId. Not the other way around. Foreign key references have a direction.